# C# listview column number change on resize in SmallIcon view

Tags: c#, listview, resize

First, I want to be clear : I'm  not talking about the ListViewColumnHeader, there are pretty much help available about columns disposition, programmative resizing, auto resize, etc..

I deal with a listview in [smallIcon view mode (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOBAb.jpg), where items are listed on *n* columns automatically.

```
LVresults.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.SmallIcon;
```

The ListView adjust the number of columns depending on each item size and the size of the Listview itself.

But, if the user perform a resize, even a vertical one, [the Listview  put every items on an unique column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQGmp.jpg) (forever !). Did someone already have to deal with SmallIcon (and LargeIcon i presume) columns ? Can you help me fix this so the ListView adjust the number of column dynamically on resize ?

Ps : The user can change the View mode with the second right button but this view is one of the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call this on resize:

```
LVresults.ArrangeIcons(ListViewAlignment.SnapToGrid);
```

Comment: Works well. `ArrangeIcons()` was in conflict with `Columns.width` which were also resized when the user selected Detail view. To avoid the bug, I simply used an `if (LVresults.View == System.Windows.Forms.View.Details) {} else {}`